# Can Jquery trigger a server-side "selectedIndexChanged" event on a DropDownList?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, event-handling

Well, that's my question.

I need to grab data from client-side (from a multiple dropdownlist), then use it on server-side on postback.

The problem is that the server-side "SelectedIndexChanged" event triggers earlier than the client-side "change" event, so the data never reaches the server-side.

So, my situation is that I want to do a function on client-side, and then execute the server-side event. Is that possible? Thank you in advance.

PS: Without using Ajax.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot do it with Ajax?  It would be super simple with Ajax.  I'm not sure if it possible without, maybe someone else will know.

Comment: The problem is a postback. My boss wants to mantain the postback at all cost. I told him it would be better if we use Ajax, but he refused. That's why I wanted to know if there is a way to do this.

Comment: I don't envy those situations. Ajax can 'post' however.  But yes, I understand it all rolls down hill sometimes. :)

Comment: Your time may be better spent convincing your boss to do it using AJAX rather then implementing any sort of "hack" to do what you're asking ;) After all, that's what AJAX is for. It's not good practice to mix client and server side functionality like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible but you have to hack your way.
After your client side event do a postback

```
__doPostBack('someEventTargetCLientId', 'eventArgument');
```

in page load

```
if(Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != null && Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == 'someEventTargetCLientId')
{
  //do your logic for drop down index change
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Now, for all those who came in here wondering the same thing, follow GoatBreeder's advice... Ajax is better (I know it, and I wish I could use it in this case) than doing this.
If you can't use it, then this is the way to go.